# Unable to hide splash screen in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to hide the splashscreen in an Ionic project once I've received a response from an API.

I'm using the following code, but the splashscreen won't hide, and simply hangs.

When I do remote debugging in chrome, I got `hide` is undefined.

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>


app.run(function($cordovaSplashscreen, TestAPI) {
    TestAPI.$promise.then(function(response) {
        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
    }, function (errResponse) {
        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`

Source [Cordova Splashscreen: methods](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#methods)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova will not load in the browser (all plugins will show as "undefined").  You need to test on an emulator or device (preferably the latter, partly because some plugins don't work in the emulator either).

Comment: I deploy it into a device and use remote debugging with Chrome and it shows `hide is undefined`. is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `$cordovaSplashscreen.hide()` in [$ionicPlatform.ready()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) or cordova [deviceready](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready)?  It could be that the splashscreen function is being called before cordova is fully loaded.  In fact, you should wrap all cordova plugin calls in one of these (I prefer `$ionicPlatform.ready()` for ionic apps).